Dynamic allocation of resources with spark and yunikorn
Is it possible to allocate resources dynamically when submitting a spark job to yunikorn?
Let’s say we just run a query with a couple of executors. Once the executors are finished, we would like them to be removed automatically such that the resources are released again. Obviously I could just stop the spark session, but when working with spark in a Jupyter notebook for example I forget this from time to time.
Does anybody have experience with such a setup (pyspark job submitted to Yunikorn)?
I've tried the following:
conf.set(‘spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled’, True)
conf.set(‘spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout’, ‘5s’)
conf.set(‘spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors’, 2)
conf.set(‘spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors’, 2)
conf.set(“spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors”, 30)
conf.set(‘spark.dynamicAllocation.schedulerBacklogTimeout’, ‘1s’)

While allocation works well, the exec are not removed anymore once my pyspark query has been run.
